# Postgres SQLalchemy automap not recognizing relationships

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Following the example from the [sqlalchemy documentation and adapting](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#generating-mappings-from-an-existing-metadata), I've gotting this code for my database:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

engine = create_engine('postgresql://u:pw@db')

metadata = MetaData(schema='name')
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['a', 'b'])

Base = automap_base(bind=engine, metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()

A, B = Base.classes.a, Base.classes.b

result = A.first()

print(result.id)
```

Running the script returns this error:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/<User>/untitled0.py", line 18, in <module>
Base.prepare(engine,reflect=True)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/automap.py", line 788, in prepare
generate_relationship)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/automap.py", line 895, in _relationships_for_fks
local_cls, referred_cls):

TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tables can be identified without a schema, eliminate the restriction then use the metadata to automap without a declarative base.

Here are links to the relevant sqlalchemy documentation:

1. [create_engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine)
2. [MetaData](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData)
3. [Table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table)
4. [select](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select)

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select

   engine = create_engine('postgresql://u:pw@db')

   metadata = MetaData(engine)

   a = Table('a', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
   b = Table('b', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

   ab = a.join(b)

   query = select([a.c.id,b.c.id]).select_from(ab)    

   result = conn.execute(query).fetchone()
   ```

Running this script will return the first record from table a and the first joined record from table b.

Note that this format is entirely dependent on the database having foreign key connections between the two tables. Additionally, using the classes will give you code completion for table.fields in most editors while this method will not.